# (Out) into the streets

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage

Example sentence:

> He put on his jacket, opened the door, and walked (out) into the streets.

According to Google Ngrams, "walked out into the streets" is [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=walked%20into%20the%20streets%2C%20walked%20out%20into%20the%20streets&year_start=1600&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwalked%20into%20the%20streets%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwalked%20out%20into%20the%20streets%3B%2Cc0) than "walked into the streets." Is the former more natural?

Comment: When speaking of leaving home or some other building, it's more usual to say _out_. I note that some of the Ngram references refer to walking into the streets of a town/city from an outdoor meeting place or from outside the town.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When two sentences are both acceptable, as both of these are, it is risky to use a difference in frequency in a Google NGram as an indication od which is more natural. Google Ngrams does not take into account context beside the phrase searched for. It looks only at books. It does not consider if a tex is quoting an old form or not. Google Ngrams can be quite useful, but one must be careful what one concludes from them, particularly when the frequency difference shown is only moderate.

> - He put on his jacket, opened the door, and walked into the streets.
> - He put on his jacket, opened the door, and walked out into the streets.

The form with out is perhaps more likely when "he" is in a building previously, as opposed to being in a park, say, or stepping out of an automobile. But either form is perfectly natural in either case, and might well be used by a fluent speaker.

Another common form would be:

> He put on his jacket, opened the door, and walked into the street.

The phrase "the street" can be used as an idiom for "the area outside" (in an urban setting). Similarly "the streets" can be used to mean "the town or city as a whole.